# Lucene - limit amount of results for specific term in search query

Tags: performance, lucene, lucene.net

The problem is that one of our terms could be very common (for example number "3"). In that case I would like to limit the amount of search result Scored while Lucene is running the Query. Is that even possible? 
Just to emphasize - I don't want just to limit Lucene search results (that could easily be done using second number parameter in IndexSearher.Search method). I want to tell Lucene something like - don't spent too much time searching hits for that specific term. In case you found, let's say, a 1,000,000 - stop looking and go to other terms.

Comment: So this is a performance problem?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. As you might know, absolute scores [are meaningless](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages) in Lucene, so there's no support for them.

Because the term is really common, the idf will be high (or low, depending on your perspective) so it will probably be relatively inconsequential due to Lucene's [pruning algorithms](http://philosophyforprogrammers.blogspot.com/2010/09/lucene-performance.html). You can always change the boost to make it matter even less, but I'd double check that this is really your performance bottleneck.